# Trying to multiply a value from django url

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a url like

```
r'^(?P<num>)\d+)$
```

and i'm trying to do something like

```
kwargs['num']*3
```

which, when num=2 is giving me a weird number like 222222222...

however if i try int(kwargs['num'])*3 then that works as expected.

can anyone explain what's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value is not an integer but a string. Convert it first:

```
int(kwargs['num']) * 3
```

Multiplying a python string means you want to repeat it:

```
>>> 'Hello ' * 3
'Hello Hello Hello '
```

The URL regular expression matches digits, but that doesn't auto-magically turn the resulting value into an integer.